# Rails, helper not outputting results of a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I trying to render a table which values for each hour of everyday of the week, I'm actually using this jquery plugin to color the chart, but the data should be output to match the one on their site here: http://www.geertdedeckere.be/shop/graphup/download/demo1/

My data is being output by rails like this:

```
@data = [
  {"day"=>1.0, "hour"=>19.0, "count"=>6623.0},
  {"day"=>1.0, "hour"=>20.0, "count"=>7242.0},
  {"day"=>1.0, "hour"=>21.0, "count"=>7148.0},
  {"day"=>1.0, "hour"=>22.0, "count"=>7196.0},
  {"day"=>1.0, "hour"=>23.0, "count"=>7244.0},
  {"day"=>2.0, "hour"=>0.0, "count"=>7147.0},
  {"day"=>2.0, "hour"=>1.0, "count"=>7217.0}
  # ...
]
```

And my helper looks like the following, and this is where the problem lies

```
def table_counts(data)
  days = 1..7
  hours = 0..23

  hours.each do |hour|
    content_tag(:td, hour)

    day_of_week = data.select {|f| f["hour"] == hour }
    day_of_week.each do |d|
      content_tag(:td, d['count']) 
    end
  end
end
```

So the major issue is in my views I don't get the `content_tag`s I just get the value of `hours`, so the output to the html is literally `0..23`, How can I have all those `td`s output via my helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`each` returns the collection iterated over.  You want [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249).  `map` returns an array that you will then want to `join`.